# Legendre polynomials that evaluated with huge difference

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm dealing with Legendre polynomials, involving the first kind, second kind, and the associated ones. However, I found this:

```
In[252]:= N[LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, Cosh[1]]]

Out[252]= -0.0681152
```

and:

```
In[251]:= LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[1]]]

Out[251]= 1.18183*10^-14 + 0. I
```

I don't know why the result are so different.

I tried to plot the graph of `LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, Cosh[x]]` with $x$ from $0$ to $3$, and the graph showed me almost zero.

I don't know if this is a bug or what. Need help!

Comment: If you change 30 to 300, the difference is even larger..

Comment: Please read the info for the tag [tag:bugs].  The tag is to be added only after a community consensus is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @MichaelE2

Comment: In summary: `LegendreQ[]` automatically evaluates to a "simpler" representation for integer order and degree, which is not necessarily numerically stable for large arguments. Either use high precision or directly feed an inexact argument to `LegendreQ[]` at the outset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use controlled precision, not machine numbers to check:

```
N[LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, Cosh[1]], 10]
(* 1.181831263*10^-14 *)
LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[1], 10]]
(* 1.1818312625*10^-14 + 0.*10^-25 I *)
```

The essential problem is that `LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, Cosh[1]]` evaluates to a power series of degree 30 in `Cosh[1]`, and power series are not generally numerically stable representations of polynomials. Thus, using `N` after the expansion without controlled precision is inaccurate.

`LegendreQ` apparently has a numerically stable method to use when fed a machine number. Thus, `LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[1]]]` is accurate even without precision control.

Comment: The OP's second machine-number computation `LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[1]]]` is accurate, so I don't understand your first sentence.  (Presumably a standard stable algorithm is used to compute `LegendreQ` on approximate numeric input.)

Answer (score 1):

John answer is the best up-vote here but want to add the trick is where to apply the N.  If you have any number inside a function applied to to N, then make sure that any number inside the function ,NOT intended to be an integer,  will have the N head applied

```
      LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[1]]]
        (* Any number not intended to be interger will need the head N *)
            LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, Cosh[N@1]]
   Plot[{LegendreQ[30, 0, 3, N[Cosh[N@x], 10]], Cosh[x]}, {x, -Pi/10000, 
  2 Pi/10000}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

*Out[9]= 1.18183*10^-14 + 0. I

Out[10]= 1.18183*10^-14 + 0. I*

[image: ![enter image description here]